# EFHW: better to get far end really high, or middle somewhat high?

Tags: antenna, efhw

I built a 40m end fed halfwave antenna and unun, and the wire is about 66 ft long. I have some tall trees nearby I can hang it in, semi-permanently.

Which of the following would be better?

A) hanging the far end nice and high, about 50ft, but then slope down the feed end to about 8ft

B) hanging the middle (inverted V) about 30ft, and getting both ends about 8ft off the ground

I don't want to deal with multiple high points in the trees, but I can get a single high point up there. So that seems to suggest these two possible options.

Thanks!

Comment: With a 30' peak, the middle portion of a V will average well below 30'.  At a 50' peak, the middle of a sloper with a 8' base will average around 29' in height.  So 29' is likely higher than well below 30'.  Consider the sloper an unfolded inverted V.

Comment: Thank you, that's a great way of thinking about it! I will try sloper, and if it's satisfactory I'm good to go. Hoping I don't have to take this thing down too soon, not a super accessible area.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you prefer to operate with vertical or horizontal polarization, but mounting one end high and the other low Might give you some unique benefits. Your range should be better then if you kept it at 8 feet, however I do not know your terrain to be sure. With it pseudo mounted in a tree you can lower and raise it easily if you want to change bands or modify the antenna setting it up for multiple bands.

Comment: Thanks. It's fairly hilly around my house, which is making me think about option B, just to get the high end somewhat above the nearby hills. But I'm reading that inverted V is generally better because EFHW radiates mostly from the center.

Comment: That works and you won't have to stand on your head:-)